# How my PHP web app can convert a video to an image of sound wave?

Tags: php, audio, video

I've got a lot of videos on a video platform called Brightcove.  I can programmatically download them through an API into my web application.  How can I programmatically create an image of a soundwave for the audio tracks in a movie?  Are there open source libraries to do this?  I'm using Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.

**Additional Notes**

Also, my videos can be in a wide range of formats...avi, mpg, mp4, flv etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these answers - I think they are just want you want. (They worked for me).
To get the audio out of the video:
[PHP Extract audio from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574223/php-extract-audio-from-video)

Then generate the waveform:
http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/

Hope these help - they sure helped me.