# PHP - How to convert video (mp4) file to mp3 music file?

Tags: php, mp3, mp4

Is it possible to convert video file (mp4 format) from remote URL to mp3 file and send converted file as downloading action ?

I tried with this: [Convert .mp4 to .mp3 using pure PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895207/convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-pure-php/18895322#18895322) but when I change `video.mp4` for remote URL with mp4 file, the script worked 4 minutes and this was max execution time on my server so it just doesn't work for me.

Is it possible to convert from MP4 format to mp3 in easy and fast way ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I can't see working solution in any suggested urls AS "POSSIBLE DUPLICATIONS".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .mp4 to .mp3 using pure PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895207/convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-pure-php)

Comment: It's probably the downloading of the MP4 that takes most of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Extract audio from video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574223/php-extract-audio-from-video)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware size of this mp4 file was 102 MB and time duration of this file is 7 minutes so I think it's normal video and my script should convert files which time duration is 10 minutes and more so... It's doesn;t solve my problem and I also can't find reply with WORKING script for my question in suggested "POSSIBLE DUPLICATIONS" urls.

Comment: Well, measure how long it takes to download, and how long it takes to convert once it has. That should give you an idea.